# Inverse of a function of a nilpotent matrix: $(I-A)^{-1}=A^2+A+I$ if $A^3=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Suppose that A is a $50 × 50$ matrix such that $A^3 = 0$. Show that the inverse of $I_{50} − A$ is $A^2 + A + I_{50}$.

I'm not even sure how to approach this problem. Any help on how to go about answering this question?

I'd like an explanation along with the solution, if possible. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know what the inverse of a matrix is, and how it relates to multiplying two matrices? How does your textbook define this?

Comment: My understanding is that the inverse is the matrix that you multiply another matrix by, in order to get the identity matrix.

Comment: Ok, so where did you run into trouble computing the product of $I - A$ and $A^2 + A + I$?

Comment: I apologise. I was misinterpreting the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(I-A)(A^2+A+I) = (A^2+A+I-A^3-A^2-A) = (-A^3 + (A^2 - A^2) + (A-A) + I) = I$

Based on your question, I am assuming the problem you were given just to show that $I-A$ is the inverse of $A^2+A+I$, and not something like "Find the inverse of $I-A$", which would require you to first use logic to deduce that $A^2+A+I$ is a reasonable formula for the inverse. (Note, I am writing $I$ as short for $I_{50}$ since there is no ambiguity on which identity I am using).

So the inverse of a matrix $T$, is the matrix $T^{-1}$ such that $TT^{-1} = I$. We do not have to worry about right or left inverses, since $I$ and $A$ are square, thus any sums and products of these matrices are square, and it is a common result for square matrices that [$AB = I$ implies $BA = I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i). If you do not know this yet, you could multiply $(I-A)$ on the left by $(A^2+A+I)$ and deduce the result very similarly.

So all I did was multiply the two together and I got the identity, so they must be inverses. The first equality uses the distributive property, the second commutativity and associativity of matrix addition, the third uses the assumption that $A^3 = 0$ and the properties of additive inverses and the additive identity (the zero matrix) to deduce that the product is $I$.

Comment: I'd appreciate an explanation of how you came to this answer.

Comment: @ThePointer Are you familiar with the distributive and commutative properties of matrices?

Comment: I apologise. I was misinterpreting the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try to multiply $I-A$ by the matrix $A^2+A+I$ on the right and on left and note what you get.